# Web API run by Docker Compose unable to access service dependency over HTTP

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have a Dockerised ASP.NET Core (2.2) Web API which depends upon another service (an Identity Provider) for bearer token validation. I've therefore used Visual Studio to add container orchestration support to my API project using Docker Compose to let me debug locally using Visual Studio with the dependency in place.

The Docker Compose services look like this:

```
services:
  my.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: My.Api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "60004:80"
    depends_on:
      - identity
  identity:
    image: "my-identity:local"
    ports:
      - "60000:80"
```

When I run the Docker Compose debug profile in Visual Studio I can see both services have started up, so I can use a browser to load anonymous endpoints of my API at http://localhost:60004 and I can also see the OIDC configuration of my Identity Provider at http://localhost:60000/.well-known/openid-configuration.

However, when I use a client app to make authorised requests to my API (passing a valid access token) it returns a 500 response containing the following error:

> IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'http://localhost:60000/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

My assumption is that a server-to-server call between the two containers (API and Identity) is failing. I confirmed this by trying to explicitly make an HTTP request to my OIDC endpoint and get back a `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address` exception.

But my understanding was that Docker Compose handled all the networking complexities of inter-dependent containers. So what else do I need to do to ensure my Identity Provider can be seen by containers that depend upon it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to access the service at `localhost`.  In most situations that's not going to work: `localhost` means "the current container" (or "the current host") and you identity service is not running in the same container as your api service.

From within your `my.api` container, you could access your identity service using the hostname `identity`, e.g., `http://identity/.well-known/openid-configuration`. This works because when you bring up a docker-compose stack, docker-compose will by default create a user-defined network for your containers. Within a user-defined network, Docker maintains a DNS service that maps container names to their respective addresses. Note that you need to access the service on the port that it's listening on inside the container (port 80), not the port on the host at which you're publishing it.

There is no need to publish the `identity` service on a host port (using the `ports` key in your service definition) unless you actually need to access this service from something other than your api container.